# File sync only downloading some files in folder

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm synchronizing from a windows machine to an Ubuntu 12.04 machine.  When I check the files on the website I can see all files uploaded from the Windows machine.

The problem I'm having is that although the cloud and the Windows machine match in terms of files, my Ubuntu machine hasn't downloaded all the files.

I'm getting no errors and my Ubuntu One client shows that the file sync is up-to-date.  I can go to my dashboard and download the file manually so there is no problem with the sync to the cloud, just from the cloud to my local machine.

Does anyone have a clue as to why I might be seeing this behaviour?